# Remove mask from image with GraphicsMagick in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I have successfully created a image with the form of a square diamond by providing an original image and a masking image with background black alpha 0 and the diamond square white with alpha 1.

I use the following gm command

```
gm composite -compose in orgiginal.jpg diamond-mask.png result.png
```

Now I would like to reproduce the result using node.js gm module.

Answer (score 0):

I think node-gm doesn't provide support for composite/compose.

However there is a fork of GM on github that may be worth exploring:
https://github.com/fanzter/gm/commit/822c917bbaaf984920e6625b65acd6d21c3ac360

Comment: Thanks, I will look it up. However I had several problems with GM and the node.js-wrapper so I ended up executing ImageMagick commands with system calls instead.